# Cubic root function cbrt() in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, root, cubic

I am writing a program in Visual Studio 2012 Professional (Windows) in C/C++ which consists of calculating many powers using `pow()`. I ran the profiler to find out why it takes such a long time to run and I found that `pow()` is the bottleneck.

I have rewritten the powers such as

`pow(x,1.5)` to `x*sqrt(x)`

and

`pow(x,1.75)` to `sqrt(x*x*x*sqrt(x))`

which significantly improved the speed of the program.

A few powers are of the kind `pow(x,1.0/3.0)` so I looked for the cubic root function `cbrt()` to speed up things but it seems not available in Visual Studio which I can hardly imagine so therefore my question:

Where can I find the `cbrt()` function in Visual Studio 2012 Professional and if not, what are the alternatives except for `pow(x,1.0/3.0)`?

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan

Comment: Is using VS2013 Express an option?

Comment: For what it's worth, using x*sqrt(x*sqrt(x)) for pow(x,1.75) should be ever so slightly faster than your alternative. (Only 1 multiplication faster though !)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This site](http://metamerist.com/cbrt/cbrt.htm) explores several computational methods to compute cube root efficiently in C, and has some source code you can download.

(**EDIT**: A google search for "[fast cube root](https://www.google.com/#q=fast+cube+root)" comes up with several more promising-looking hits.)

> Cube roots are a topic of interest, because they're used in many common formulae and a fast cube root function isn't included with Microsoft Visual Studio.
>
> In the absence of a special cube root function, a typical strategy is calculation via a power function (e.g., pow(x, 1.0/3.0)). This can be problematic in terms of speed and in terms of accuracy when negative numbers aren't handled properly.

His site has some benchmarks on the methods used. All of them are much faster than `pow()`.

> ```
> 32-bit float tests
> ----------------------------------------
> cbrt_5f      8.8 ms    5 mbp   6.223 abp
> pow        144.5 ms   23 mbp  23.000 abp
> halley x 1  31.8 ms   15 mbp  18.961 abp
> halley x 2  59.0 ms   23 mbp  23.000 abp
> newton x 1  23.4 ms   10 mbp  12.525 abp
> newton x 2  48.9 ms   20 mbp  22.764 abp
> newton x 3  72.0 ms   23 mbp  23.000 abp
> newton x 4  89.6 ms   23 mbp  23.000 abp
> ```

See the site for downloadable source.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Golang Go implementation has quite an extensive assembly/go math library. The basic algorithm should be decipherable without much Go knowledge, and the code is BSD licensed. For `cbrt`, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/math/cbrt.go)

Comment: Since this answer fully answers my question I'll accept this answer! Thank you very much

Comment: Since this answer was posted, the site linked has gone offline. Wayback machine link: http://web.archive.org/web/20131227144655/http://metamerist.com/cbrt/cbrt.htm

Answer (score 0):

Implementation below is 4x faster than std::pow with relatively higher tolerance (0.000001) on an AVX-512 CPU. It is made of vertically auto-vectorizable loops for every basic operation like multiplication and division so that it computes 8,16,32 elements at once instead of horizontally vectorizing the Newton-Raphson loop.

```
#include <cmath> 
/* 
   Newton-Raphson iterative solution
   f_err(x) = x*x*x - N
   f'_err(x) = 3*x*x
   x = x - (x*x*x - N)/(3*x*x)
   x = x - (x - N/(x*x))/3   <--- repeat until error < tolerance
   but with vertical-parallelization 
*/
template < typename Type, int Simd, int inverseTolerance> 
    inline 
void cubeRootFast(Type *const __restrict__ data, 
        Type *const __restrict__ result) noexcept 
{ 
    // alignment 64 required for AVX512 vectorization
    alignas(64) 
    Type xd[Simd]; 

    alignas(64) 
    Type resultData[Simd]; 

    alignas(64) 
    Type xSqr[Simd]; 

    alignas(64) 
    Type nDivXsqr[Simd]; 

    alignas(64) 
    Type diff[Simd]; 

    // cube root checking mask
    for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
    { 
        xd[i] = data[i] <= Type(0.000001);
    } 

    // skips division by zero if input is zero or close to zero
    for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
    { 
        resultData[i] = xd[i] ? Type(1.0) : data[i]; 
    } 

    // Newton-Raphson Iterations in parallel 
    bool work = true; 
    while (work) 
    { 
        // compute x*x
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            xSqr[i] = resultData[i] *resultData[i]; 
        } 

        // compute N/(x*x)
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            nDivXsqr[i] = data[i] / xSqr[i]; 
        } 

        // compute x - N/(x*x)
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            nDivXsqr[i] = resultData[i] - nDivXsqr[i]; 
        } 

        // compute (x-N/(x*x))/3
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            nDivXsqr[i] = nDivXsqr[i] / Type(3.0); 
        } 

        // compute x - (x-N/(x*x))/3
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            diff[i] = resultData[i] - nDivXsqr[i]; 
        } 

        // compute error
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            diff[i] = resultData[i] - diff[i]; 
        } 

        // compute absolute error
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            diff[i] = std::abs(diff[i]); 
        } 

        // compute condition to stop looping (error < tolerance)?
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            diff[i] = diff[i] > Type(1.0/inverseTolerance); 
        } 

        // all SIMD lanes have to have zero work left to end
        Type check = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            check += diff[i]; 
        } 
        work = (check > Type(0.0)); 

        // compute the next x guess
        for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
        { 
            resultData[i] = resultData[i] - nDivXsqr[i]; 
        } 
    } 

    // if input was close to zero, output zero
    // output result otherwise
    for (int i = 0; i < Simd; i++) 
    { 
        result[i] = xd[i] ? Type(0.0) : resultData[i]; 
    } 
} 
#include <iostream> 
 
int main() 
{ 
    constexpr int n = 8192; 
    constexpr int simd = 16; 
    constexpr int inverseTolerance = 1000;
    float data[n]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        data[i] = i; 
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += simd) 
    { 
        cubeRootFast<float, simd, inverseTolerance> (data + i, data + i); 
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        std::cout << data[i *i *i] << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

It is tested only with GCC so it may require extra MSVC-pragmas on each loop to force auto-vectorization. If you have OpenMP, then you can also use `#pragma omp simd safelen(Simd)` to achieve same thing.

The performance only holds within [0,1] range. To use bigger values, you should use range reduction like this:

```
// example: max value is 1000
for(auto & input:inputs)
    input = input/1000.0f // normalize

for(..)
    cubeRootFast<float, simd, inverseTolerance> (input + i, input + i)

 for(auto & input:inputs)
    input = 10.0f*input // de-normalize  (1000 = 10 x 10 x 10)
```

---

If you need only 0.005 error on low-range like [0,1000] with 16x speedup, you can try below implementation that uses polynomial approximation (Horner-Scheme is applied to compute with FMA instructions and no explicit auto-vectorization required since it doesn't include any branching/loop inside):

```
// optimized for [0,1] range: ~1 cycles on AVX512, 0.003 average error 
// polynomial approximation with Horner Scheme for FMA optimization 
template<typename T> 
T cubeRootFast(T x) 
{ 
 T xd = x-T(1.0); 
 T result = T(-55913.0/4782969.0); 
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(21505.0/1594323.0);  
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(-935.0/59049.0);  
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(374.0/19683.0);  
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(-154.0/6561.0);  
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(22.0/729.0);  
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(-10.0/243.0); 
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(5.0/81.0); 
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(-1.0/9.0);  
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(1.0/3.0); 
 result *= xd; 
 result += T(1.0); 
 return result; 
} 
 
// range reduction + dereduction: ~ 1 cycles on AVX512 
 for(int i=0;i<8192;i++) 
 {  
     float inp = input[i]; 
     // scaling + descaling for range [1,999] 
     float scaling = (inp>333.0f)?(1000.0f):(333.0f); 
     scaling = (inp>103.0f)?scaling:(103.0f); 
     scaling = (inp>29.0f)?scaling:(29.0f); 
     scaling = (inp>7.0f)?scaling:(7.0f); 
     scaling = (inp>3.0f)?scaling:(3.0f); 
      
     output[i] = powf(scaling,0.33333333333f)*cubeRootFast<float>(inp/scaling);  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

MSC 2012 must be about their last version that didn't have cbrt implemented in math.h. The MS system cbrt benchmarks terribly but isn't so bad in real code. It is not the most  accurate though.

Best combination of public code for cbrt I have found that is both accurate and fast on most compilers is [Sun's implementation](https://cgit.freebsd.org/src/tree/lib/msun/src/s_cbrt.c) of Kahan's magic constant algorithm by Bruce Evans. Intel's system cbrt in their 2023 compiler is unbelievably accurate through careful use of truncation and FMA in the final refinement.

An easy alternative if there is nothing better to hand is:

```
double cbrt(double x)
{  // fast and accurate. NR isn't sufficient to tidy it up
   // could be improved by precision (y*y)*y-x using FMA
   double t, y;
   if (x) y = exp(log(abs(x)) / 3); else return x;
   if (x<0) y = -y;
   t = y*y*y;
   return y - y * (t - x) / (2 * t + x);  // Halley refinement
}
```

Depending on the CPU architecture either of these are worth a try.